# How to run a file in c++?

Tags: c++, winapi

Code looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string command;
    #define cfile
        ShellExecute(GetDesktopWindow(), "open", NULL, "file.exe" SW_SHOWNORMAL)

    cin >> command;
    
    if (command=="file");
    {
        cfile;
    }   
}
```

The file's directory is in the environment variables of Windows, so it should be fine running it by just "file.exe". I see this working for other people sometimes, however I have no clue why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Why not to use `system()` - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system

Comment: The `#define` and the substitution text need to be on the same line or the newline needs to be escaped.

Comment: Why is this a macro at all?

Comment: Note that your `if` has an errorneous `;` on it that needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right off the bat, you're missing a comma between parameters, it should look like this:

```
// still wrong
#define cfile ShellExecute(GetDesktopWindow(), "open", NULL, "file.exe", SW_SHOWNORMAL)
```

Now that we got the most basic syntax problems fixed, other problems are:

- You never set the parent of the process the desktop window, use a `null` parent instead.
- You can use `null` as the verb if you're just opening a file anyway
- However a `null` file makes no sense
- You're also missing the working folder

So with those in mind, you should use this instead:

```
#define cfile ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, "file.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
```

Comment: One should never use `ShellExecute/Ex()` to run an `.exe` file, unless you are using the `runas` verb to run it elevated. Otherwise, use `CreateProcess()` instead (which `ShellExecute/Ex()` will delegate to anyway, so just cut out the middle man).